# Timer dizendo quando está acabando

Tags: c#

Como posso fazer para o timer avisar quando está acabando no Console? Ele limpa o console a cada 1 hora

Exemplo:

```
> Falta 3 segundos para o terminar
> Falta 2 segundos para o terminar
> Falta 1 segundos para o terminar
```

Timer:

```
private static void Timer(Object o)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            GC.Collect();
        }

Timer t = new Timer(Timer, null, 0, 3600000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O intervalo do `timer` tem que ser de 1 segundo, pois, a cada um segundo ele vai verificar se está na hora de limpar o console, ou se estiver <= 5, escrever na tela 5...4...3...2...1...

Em outra variável, você guarda o intervalo para executar o comando `Clear`, e a cada segundo, você o decrementa, até que chegue a 0, e então limpa o console, e restaura o intervalo.

Fiz o seguinte exemplo:

```
class Program
{
    static TimeSpan intervalo;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        intervalo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        Timer t = new Timer(ClearConsole, null, 0, 1000);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Aplicação rodando...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }


    }

    private static void ClearConsole(object state)
    {
        if (intervalo.TotalSeconds == 0)
        {
            intervalo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            Console.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            intervalo = intervalo - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            if (intervalo.TotalSeconds <=5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Console será limpo em " + intervalo.TotalSeconds + " segundos...");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Como ficaria se eu precisasse que o console limpe a cada 1 hora? Eu teria que colocar o timer do console de uma hora e o intervalo também?

Comment: @BetaDarkNight basta que o intervalo seja 3600 segundos, ou seja `intervalo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);`

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma também, talvez não seja a melhor mas funciona:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tempoDuracao = 5; // Em segundos se por 3600 se torna uma hora e assim por diante
            var cronometro = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tempoDuracao);

            while (tempoDuracao != 0)
            {
                if (tempoDuracao > 3)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine(cronometro);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempoDuracao == 3)
                        Console.Clear();

                    if (tempoDuracao == 1)
                        Console.WriteLine("Falta " + cronometro.Seconds + " segundo para o programa terminar");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Faltam " + cronometro.Seconds + " segundos para o programa terminar");
                }

                cronometro = cronometro.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                tempoDuracao--;
            }
        }
    }
```